# Is there a more efficient way of choosing an element from 1 array and to every element of the same array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I want to, for every element of an array ZAbs, compare it for equality to every element of the array itself and put them into another distinct array. I want the distinct array's elements to have the same index as the ZAbs array.

I did this by creating 4 nested for loops:

```
for pAbs2 = 1:400

    for qAbs2 = 1:300

        zAbsCompare = ZAbs(qAbs2, pAbs2);

        for pAbs3 = 1:400

            for qAbs3 = 1:300

                zAbsCompare2 = ZAbs(qAbs3, pAbs3);

                if (zAbsCompare == zAbsCompare2)

                    InitialZModEqualsImag(pAbs2,qAbs2) = InitialZImag(qAbs2, pAbs2);
                    InitialZModEqualsReal(pAbs2,qAbs2) = InitialZReal(qAbs2, pAbs2);

                end

            end

        end

    end

end
```

However, this runs really slowly. I can't think of a better way to do this, but as I'm inexperienced with MATLAB there's probably something I'm overlooking here. Any help?

EDIT: Fixed an error and restated the question.

Comment: Please indent the code correctly. Select the code in the Matlab editor and press CTRL+I

Comment: I don't follow the assignments.  You will be overwriting values from previous iterations...

Comment: You're right, this isn't written correctly. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the comparison (not sure that's what you want) efficently with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
comp = bsxfun(@eq, X, shiftdim(X,-2));
```

The result `comp(m,n,p,q)` is `1` if `X(m,n) == X(p,q)`, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: I think this may help, but why would I want to shift dimensions of array X?

Comment: @user2993946 You need four dimensions to contain the result: two for each of the elements to be compared. If you didn't shift, the comparison with `bsxfun(@eq...)` would only compare element (1,1) with (1,1); element (1,2) with (1,2) etc (giving of course all ones)

Comment: @user2993946 If the comparison is not exactly what you want, please explain further. Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: I want an array such that if X(i,j) == X(p,q) then the values are assigned to Y(i,j) and Y(p,q) respectively. The issue I'm having is that to do this, I have to create 4 for loops to choose every combination of i,j,p and q respectively.

Comment: @user2993946 Simply doing `Y = X` would satisfy your criterion: if X(i,j) == X(p,q) then the values are assigned to Y(i,j) and Y(p,q). What do you want to do if X(i,j) is not equal to X(p,q)?

Comment: I held back on giving this answer because while compact and fast, it is not memory efficient, requiring 14.4 GB for the 300x400 matrix in question.

Comment: @chappjc Very true! I didn't check the size of the input array